# Scanned input inside a do-while loop doesn't reset properly on the next iteration

Tags: java, loops, do-while

My program is meant to add up all the even integers between 2 and an input number which is between 20 and 60. The logic for that is correct and will work, but it's supposed to be able to run again if the user wishes, and when it runs again, the input only changes if you input a new integer higher than the previous iteration. If you enter one lower, it just uses the same integer input as before. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice_7_1
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int input;
      int i = 2;
      int sum = 0;
      int restart;
      do
      {
         System.out.print ("\nEnter a value between 20 and 60: ");
         input = scan.nextInt();

         if (input >= 20 && input <= 60) // checks validity of input
         {
            while (i <= input)
            {
               sum = sum + i;
               i = i + 2;
            }
            System.out.println ("\nSum of even numbers between 2 and " + 
            input + " is: " + sum);
            }
         else 
         {
            System.out.println ("\nInput is not between 20 and 60. ");
         }

         System.out.print ("\nEnter a new value? (1 for yes, any other number
         for no): ");
         restart = scan.nextInt();
      } while (restart == 1);
    }
}
```

So for example, if I enter 20 as the input, the program outputs:

> Sum of even numbers between 2 and 20 is: 110
>
> Enter a new value? (1 for yes, any other number for no):

and then I enter 30 (same run of the program):

> Sum of even numbers between 2 and 30 is: 240
>
> Enter a new value? (1 for yes, any other number for no):

and then I try to enter 20 again:

> Sum of even numbers between 2 and 20 is: 240
>
> Enter a new value? (1 for yes, any other number for no):

(Should clearly be 110, not 240)

My initial thought was that it wasn't actually scanning for a new input on the second iteration, but because it will work if I keep giving it inputs of greater value I know that is not true.

Comment: What happens if you set `input` to zero at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: I did try that, nothing different happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code inside main()

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int input;
      int i = 2;
      int sum = 0;
      int restart;
      do
      {
         System.out.print ("\nEnter a value between 20 and 60: ");
         input = scan.nextInt();

         if (input >= 20 && input <= 60) // checks validity of input
         {
             i = 2;
             sum = 0;
            while (i <= input)
            {
               sum = sum + i;
               i = i + 2;
            }
            System.out.println ("\nSum of even numbers between 2 and " + 
            input + " is: " + sum);
            }
         else 
         {
            System.out.println ("\nInput is not between 20 and 60. ");
         }

         System.out.print ("\nEnter a new value? (1 for yes, any other number for no): ");
         restart = scan.nextInt();
      } while (restart == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I had tried initializing the input again but I just realized it was int i that needed to be reset to 2.

Comment: I prefer using for loops, especially when nesting is involved. Because then you don't need to explicitly initialize the counters. Since, initializing is embedded as part of the syntax